# Парсинг даты в C

Tags: c, datetime

нужно спарсить дату время в следующем формате `2021-10-11T09:00:00+00:00` первое что пришло в голову использовать `sscanf` есть ли решения понадежней?

Comment: если в рамках POSIX, то есть `strptime()`... а в рамках голого стандарта `sscanf()` вполне сойдёт...

Comment: Если все данные поступают в таком единственном формате — вполне. Если нужна защита от дурака, то...

Comment: "Парсинг — это автоматизированный сбор общедоступной информации из интернета, осуществляемый без использования API сайтов."

Comment: @AlexGlebe Это все же [веб-скрейпинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)...

Comment: ну тогда это анти-парсинг "Синтаксический анализатор (жарг. па́рсер ← англ. parser) — это программа или часть программы, выполняющая синтаксический анализ. " @Harry Я так и не понял, из даты в строку или наоборот?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Давайте исходить из обычного понимания программистско-блатного жаргона. "Парсинг" обычно означает "анализ", иногда — синтаксический, иногда — лексический. Поэтому, думаю, вопрос стоит в анализе и разборе на составные части даты и времени, представленных в виде показанной строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо разобрать строку с датой на элементы, то используем *strptime(...)*.
Если наооборот, надо создать строку заданного формата, то используем *strftime(...)*.

Пример для обоих вариантов:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int  main(void) {
   struct tm tm;
   char buf[255];

   memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
   strptime("2001-11-12 18:31:01", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
   strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d %b %Y %H:%M", &tm);
   puts(buf);
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Как уже отметил fat-zer, это работает при поддержке POSIX.